# SOAP webservice: Multiple references to the same object in SOAP result

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, jax-rs, jboss7.x

I'm building a SOAP service to be used in JBoss 7.1. Until now I'm only using annotations and no XML files of generated files. Both server and client work fine for POJO's.

However, I have objects referring to other objects which I'd like to be part of the SOAP response. I could use the `@XmlElement` annotation, but when an object is referenced multiple times, it is included multiple times as well. I try to work around this by using the `@XmlIDREF` annotation, but that results in `NULL` object on the client side.

I've create a stand-alone example with `Wheel` objects referencing the `Bike` they belong to, and a service to retrieve all wheels (this is the short, incomplete code. See below for a link to the actual code):

```
@WebService
public interface IWheelService {
    Collection<Wheel> getAllWheels();
}

public class Wheel extends XmlEntity {
    private String type;
    private Bike bike;

    public Wheel(Bike bike, String type) {
        this.bike = bike;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @XmlIDREF
    public Bike getBike() {
        return bike;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}

public class Bike extends XmlEntity {
    private String color;

    public Bike(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}

public abstract class XmlEntity implements Serializable {
    public static int idGenerator = 0;
    private int id = idGenerator++;

    @XmlTransient
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    @Transient
    public String getXmlId() {
        return String.format("%s:%d", this.getClass().getSimpleName(), this.id);
    }
}
```

The full code for this example is available [here](https://github.com/jvdvTechno/jaxws-issue/tree/master).

Below is the SOAP response, containing the right bike-id for the wheels, but not the actual bike-elements. Thus `wheel.getBike()` will always return `NULL` on the client.

Is there an annotation to make JAX-WS send all related objects? Or to at least obtain bike-ids on the client so I can retrieve them with a second SOAP-request?

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getAllWheelsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://demo/">
            <return id="Wheel:1">
                <bike>Bike:0</bike>
                <type>slick</type>
            </return>
            <return id="Wheel:2">
                <bike>Bike:0</bike>
                <type>spike</type>
            </return>
        </ns2:getAllWheelsResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```